# what is difference between AJAX request, regular HTTP call and REST API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, webserver, rest

I am really confused regarding these terms. According to my understanding, an ajax request can only fetch your data but a REST API can add data to the database.Can someone please help

Answer (score 1):

**AJAX** stands for "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML", it is just a term. It uses HTTP to make requests to a web server.

An AJAX request is not just used to fetch data, it can be used to make any request be it getting data, posting data or deleting data. What it basically comes down to is making an asynchronous call and then using JavaScript to load the response data without needing to reload the page. Read more here [AJAX - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)

**HTTP** stands for "Hypertext Transfer Protocol".

It is a protocol for transmitting hypermedia such as HTML trough the web. Basically a client may open a request and the server will respond accordingly. Read more here - [HTTP - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP)

An **API** is an "Application Programming Interface" it is a way for computers to talk to each other if you think about it like that, or for you as a developer to interact with a technology someone as built.

**REST** stands for "Representational State Transfer" and is an architectural style that Roy Fielding came up with on his 2000 dissertation [Architectural Styles and
the Design of Network-based Software Architectures](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm).

So a **REST API** is just a way to build an API that follows a set of "rules", for example, using hypermedia, being stateless, and using correct status codes. There is a lot to learn about REST to really get it right and it is a complex topic to discuss in a short answer, so I advise that you read more on this subject.